# Display:table for IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-tables

I've a several columns in CSS, with float:left property to align them horizontally. But as it float in the left side, I can't center all the divs.

So I found that if I wrap my columns with another div with display:table property, all works perfectly... but not in **IE7** (idd, this property is not supported -.-).

Does anybody has a hack or trick for this?

Here is my code:

```
<div style="display:table">
 <div style="float:left">A column</div>
 <div style="float:left">A column</div>
 <div style="float:left">A column</div>
 <div style="float:left">A column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean that you "can't center all the divs" using floats? You want to be in the center of the page?

Comment: That's right, my parent div must be in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, why are you having a float: left on your leftmost div? I think that will cause some trouble. Do you have any css? You should have margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto on your outer div. Take a look on [this page](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Horizontal-Centering), there's all the details. Seems like you might have to add br-tags or similar too

Answer (score 0):

if you use `display:table;` on the parent dic, you should have `display:table-row;` and `display:table-column;`-elements in it - and floating doesn't make any sense in that case. please take a look at [this](http://www.css4you.de/display.html) or ask google for more information.

(if you want to display a table, why don't you use the `table`-element? In cases where tables are used for layout, thats a bad practice, but doing the same sh*** by substituting table-crap for [divitis](http://csscreator.com/divitis) doesn't make it better)

**EDIT:** if you just want to display your divs side by side and centered, you could simply try to use `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` (but the last will make problems in IE, too) - and remove that senseless `display:table;` on the parent-div

Comment: the display:table was only a "trick" to center all divs. So let's delete these float and apply and inline-block on my columns. The results is still the same, a bit more clean, but still does not work on IE.. :/

Comment: *sidenote:* `<table>` elements are not suggested for layout in HTML5